# Why does DistributedCache mangle my file names

Tags: java, path, uri, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a weird problem, DistributedCache appears to change the names of my files, it uses the original name as the parent folder and adds the file as a child.

i.e. folder\filename.ext becomes folder\filename.ext\filename.ext

Any ideas, my code is below.
Thanks
Akintayo

```
String paramsLocation="/user/fwang/settings/ecgparams.txt";
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(paramsLocation), firstStageConf);

Path[] paths = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(job);
 for (Path path: paths) {
  if (path.getName().equals(ecgParamsFilename)) {
   File f = new File(path.toString());
    if (f.exists()) {
     ecgParamsFullFileName = f.getAbsolutePath();
     //this becomes /user/fwang/settings/ecgparams.txt/ecgparams.txt 
    }
  }
 }
```

Update: 16 August 2010
Replacing the original call with the following, stops the mangling of the names.

```
DistributedCache.addCacheArchive(new URI(ecgParamsLocation), firstStageConf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use `addCacheArchive()`? There is a `addCacheFile()` http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.15.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html#getCacheFiles%28org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration%29 as well.